# Error when trying to specify VHDL standard in GHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

New with GHDL. This is my VHDL code:

```
/*
Name: test.vhd
Description: Demonstrates basic design in VHDL code.
Date: 04. August 2017 AD
*/

--first part: libraries
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

--second part: entity declaration
entity myEntity is
    port(a, b, c: in STD_LOGIC; y: out STD_LOGIC);
end;

--third part: entity implementation
architecture aom of myEntity is
begin
    y <= not b and (c or a and b);
end;
```

Trying to compile this with `ghdl -s test.vhd` gives me this error: `test.vhd:1:1:error: block comment are not allowed before vhdl 2008`.

So I try this: `ghdl --std=08 -s test.vhd` and I get this: `ghdl:error: unknown command '--std=08', try --help`.

Comment: command (-s) first. [Invoking GHDL — GHDL 2017-03-01 documentation](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Invoking_GHDL.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: **myentity.vhdl:19:28:error: only one type of logical operators may be used to combine relation** Use `y <= not b and (c or a) and b;` See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9. Expressions, 9.1 General. The BNF defines the syntax requirement for the parentheses in a relation - shift_expression - simple_expression - term - factor - primary  production expansion involving different logical operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be compiled this way: `ghdl -s --std=08 test.vhd`.
So, `-s` flag should go first.
All credits go to [user1155120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155120/user1155120).